# Monotone Convergence for Decreasing Functions

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

I'm trying to prove the Monotone Convergence Theorem for decreasing sequences, namely if

Let $(X,\mathcal{M},\mu)$ be a measure space and suppose $\{f_n\}$ are non-negative measurable functions decreasing pointwise to $f$. Suppose also that $f_1 \in \mathscr{L}(\mu)$. Then $$\int_X f~d\mu = \lim_{n\to\infty}\int_X f_n~d\mu.$$

Why does this statement not follow from LDCT with $f_n$ being dominated by $f_1$?

I'm also aware of the solutions with $g_n=f_1-f_n$, but the question asks to prove it using Fatou's lemma

Comment: In Fatou's lemma, the inequality goes the other way. So the inequality $\lim\int f_n\,d\mu\le\int f\,d\mu$ doesn't follow from Fatou.

Comment: @grand_chat why does the statement not follow from LDCT with $g=f_1$?

Comment: I think it does follow from LDCT.

Comment: @JohnMa Then why does every solution use the $g_n=f_1-f_n$ trick and MCT?

Comment: I guess that's because LDCT is an overkill? (It seems that LDCT is the last theorem to prove, either Fatou or MCT comes first)

Comment: @JohnMa That's peculiar, since the problem is given at the end of ch 1 of big rudin, which proves LDCT before the problems are posed.

Comment: Certainly it follows from DCT. Why do you say every solution uses that $g_n=f_1-f_n$ thing instead? I mean have you seen every solution? It's not like there's an official solution set somewhere...

Answer (score 2):

As you say in the comments, the problem is posed at the end of the first chapter of Rudin's *Real and Complex Analysis*, so it is not clear whether Rudin intends the student to use the Monotone Convergence Theorem, Fatou's Lemma or the Dominated Convergence Theorem.

You are right that the proof is a trivial application of DCT. However, it is certainly an instructive exercise to prove it using just MCT or Fatou's Lemma.