# Does convergence theorem holds for decreasing function?

Tags: lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

I was wondering there is no convergence monotone theorem for decreasing function, i.e. if $\varphi _n\searrow f$ and $f\geq 0$, why it may not hold that $$\lim_{n\to \infty }\int_X \varphi _n=\int_Xf\ \ ?$$

So, I saw [this link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1471212/monotone-convergence-for-decreasing-functions), but they don't give an example of such sequence.

Comment: $\chi_{(n,\infty)}$ on the real line.

Answer (score 1):

Take for example $$\varphi _n(x)=\infty \boldsymbol 1_{(0,\frac{1}{n})}.$$

Then $\varphi _n\searrow f$, but $\int \varphi _n=\infty $ for all $n$. Notice that this theorem holds if $\int \varphi _n<\infty $ for some $n$ (by DCT).